# Magento 2 | CPU Load goes High showing php-fpm7 process ID on top Command

Tags: magento2, server-setup, deployment

we have setup Magento 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 TLS, We are using nginx Web Server and php 7.0 installed on Machine. When we run application all CPU Utilisation showing 100% and eating server memory very quickly, We have changed www.conf file in php-fpm but not fixed the problem due to this website not responding after 5 minutes of reboot the machine we are not rebooting the machine every minute.Kindly share the valuable feedback on this so that we can fix the problem

Comment: You should check magento code, this can be because of some incorrect written code too.

Comment: you have low cpu and developer mode?